# Angular ng-repeat - need to grab the total in loop and use later on page without performance hit with extra calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `ng-repeat` that I want to "capture" or "hold" the value and use later on down the page OUTSIDE OF THE LOOP.

Example:

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-repeat="paymentTravel in payment.travelers">
   div --  Passenger {{ $index + 1 }}  /div  
   div -- {{paymentTravel.totalFare }}   /div
   GET TOTAL LENGTH save to ??
</div>

 <br>
   <div> DISPLAY THE LENGTH (total number of rows) TOTAL HERE</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to explicitly count them, because it's an array, the length property will be available so you should be able to use this:

```
<div> DISPLAY THE LENGTH {{payment.travelers.length}} TOTAL HERE</div>
```

Comment: Oh ya  -   that works.   1.  Any performance hit with this?   2.  What if I wanted to (curious of angular power)  do something like  in controller with `$scope.myRowCount`  and then set it in the loop or even in the controller ?  and then how could i use the variable?

Comment: $scope.myRowCount=$scope.payment.travelers.length; this can be done in controller and can be used anywhere in the current scope.

Comment: 1. performance hit: almost none, as you just count the items in the array and no extra things are done. 2) i would not suggest doing what you asked but it should be possible. Create a scope variable in your controller. You should be able to set values to it using: {{myRowCount=x;""}}

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987949/how-to-assign-a-dynamic-variable-in-html-using-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Use Array [**arr.length**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property to get the counts of the objects in an array.

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.payment = {
      travelers : [
        {
         totalFare : "500"
        },
        {
        totalFare : "1000"
        },
        {
        totalFare : "1200"
        },
        {
        totalFare : "1500"
        }
      ]
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="container-fluid" ng-repeat="paymentTravel in payment.travelers">
   Passenger {{ $index + 1 }}  
   {{paymentTravel.totalFare }}
</div>
<br>
<div> DISPLAY THE LENGTH {{payment.travelers.length}} TOTAL HERE</div>
</div>
```